# Invalid cast from double to datetime error

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi I am getting invalid cast from double to datetime error when i run my ASP.NET MVC code.

This is my code :

**Update**: Hi I am adding my full code below. Please have a look into that.

```
       Boolean locked = false;
        if (frmcollection["lockStart"] != null && frmcollection["lockStart"] != "")
        {
            locked = Convert.ToBoolean(frmcollection["lockStart"].ToString());

        }
        else if (datelock == "")
        {
            locked = Convert.ToBoolean("0");
        }
        Boolean valid = true;
        double inteval = 86400000 * Convert.ToDouble(frmcollection["autoFrequency"].ToString());

        DateTime schedulestartDate = Convert.ToDateTime(frmcollection["autoStart"].ToString());

        int startHour = Convert.ToInt32(frmcollection["autoStartHour"].ToString());
        DateTime sd = schedulestartDate;

        sd.AddHours(startHour);


        DateTime filterStart = Convert.ToDateTime(frmcollection["periodStart"].ToString());

        int filterStartHour = Convert.ToInt32(frmcollection["periodStartHour"].ToString());
        DateTime fsd = filterStart;

        fsd.AddHours(filterStartHour);

        DateTime filterEnd = Convert.ToDateTime(frmcollection["periodEnd"].ToString());

        int filterEndHour = Convert.ToInt32(frmcollection["periodEndHour"].ToString());
        DateTime fed = filterEnd;

        fed.AddHours(filterEndHour);


        double sDate = sd.Second;
        double sPeriod = sDate - fsd.Second;
        double ePeriod = sDate - fed.Second;

        if (sPeriod < ePeriod || sPeriod < 0 || ePeriod < 0)
        {
            valid = false;
        }

        if (valid)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
          DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(sDate + (inteval * i));

                if (locked)
                {
                    DateTime psdate = Convert.ToDateTime(sDate - sPeriod);
                }
                else
                {
                    DateTime psdate = Convert.ToDateTime(sDate + (inteval * i) - sPeriod);
                }
                DateTime pedate = Convert.ToDateTime(sDate + (inteval * i) - ePeriod);

            }
        }
        else
        {

        }
```

When i debug I am gettin error in this line :

```
  DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(sDate + (inteval * i));
```

Can someone help me in this??

Comment: Your values looks like part of a `TimeSpan`, how you expect to convert some seconds to a `DateTime` type object ?

Comment: Have you tried using DateTime.FromSeconds ?

Comment: @shirbr510, where do you see `DateTime.FromSeconds` ?? I guess you meant `TimeSpan.FromSeconds`

Comment: Sorry, I meant Timespan. FromSeconds.

Comment: @shirbr510 if i use timespan.fromseconds like this DateTime date = TimeSpan.FromSeconds (sDate + (inteval * i));, i get Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.TimeSpan' to 'System.DateTime'

Comment: you may then use the `Convert.ToDateTime(TimeSpan)` method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're adding a `double` to whatever `interval * i` resolves to.

You can't convert (cast) that to a `DateTime`, which is exactly what the error is telling you.

Comment: Hi I edited my post. I paste my full code. Have a look into that and if you dont mind can show me solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

It seems as if you're looking for the date some (interval * i) seconds after the date "sd". If so, try:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    DateTime date = sd.AddSeconds(inteval * i);

    if (locked)
    {
                DateTime psdate = sd.AddSeconds(-sPeriod);
            }
            else
            {
                DateTime psdate = sd.AddSeconds((inteval * i) - sPeriod));
            }
            DateTime pedate = sd.AddSeconds((inteval * i) - ePeriod);
   }
   //...
```

Comment: Hi your code runs fine but i think there is something wrong in this logic. I get unexpected results if i use your code.

Comment: @Ajay what result did you expect and what result did you get?

Comment: @Ajay `double inteval = 86400000 * Convert.ToDouble(frmcollection["autoFrequency"].ToString());` -- it looks like you're using ms instead of seconds.

Answer (score 0):

`DateTime` has a lot of methods to perform calculations on a specific date. For example `DateTime.AddMillisecons` which takes a double and returns a date.

[MSDN DateTime.AddMilliseconds](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.datetime.addmilliseconds%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)